# Referencing an object in python?

Tags: python, object, text, reference

Hi I have a file with a bunch of objects (the objects are Users and they store screennames and keys and codes and whatnot)...

```
user1 = User('blah', 'blah','blah','blah', 'blah')
user2 = User('blah', 'blah','blah','blah', 'blah')
user3 = User('blah', 'blah','blah','blah', 'blah')
```

and then in another file I ask for input to choose which user aka

```
user_answer = raw_input("Enter user: ")
```

and you type in "user1" so it looks like..

"Enter user: user1"

but this just links user_answer to the words "user1" and not to the actual object with the data

How could I make user_answer equal to the object user1 user2 or user3 (or user18) based on the input??

Comment: Store your users in a dictionary or list (mapping names to objects, or indices to objects).

Comment: figured it out thanks!